# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string , or a class/function , but got: undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, import

**App.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from './screens/home';
import Navigator from './routes/drawer';
import Login from './screens/login';

export default class App extends React.Component{

    render() {
        if (false) {
            return (
                <Navigator />
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <Login />
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**login.js:**

```
import React, {View, Text} from 'react';

export default class Login extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ padding: 20 }}>
                <Text>Some text</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

This program gives me the error in the title, this DOES work for the Navigator but not for the Login (when the if is set to true instead of false the program runs correctly.) The Navigator acts as a typical drawer container for an android app, but at the bottom of the imports everything appears to act the same as for rendering options. The full error log is below...

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. 
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named exports.

Check the render method of 'Login'.

This error is located at:
in Login...
in App...RCTView...AppContainer...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your imports are wrong.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
```

There is no export called `View` or `Text` inside the `react` module.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Login.js file. Some imports are wrong!

Check the components and API inside React Native [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/components-and-apis)

**SOLUTION**

Remove imports **View** and **Text** from **react**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ padding: 20 }}>
                <Text>Some text</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```